# Issues with linking armadillo and libacml

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, armadillo

I'm working on a small Neural Network, mostly just as a training example (I wanna be able to do it myself before using mlpack)
So I tried to install acml to accelerate some of the matrix operations with my gpu. I wasn't able to get it to work, so I tried disabling it, and now I'm stuck with this warning at compile time
`/usr/bin/ld: warning: libacml_mp.so, needed by /usr/lib64/libarmadillo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)`

Naturally, at runtime I get the following error: 
`/home/sapphie/Documents/CLionProjects/FirstNNTest/cmake-build-debug/FirstNNTest: error while loading shared libraries: libacml_mp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I've tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH variables, I've tried tinkering with rpath and rpath link, and nothing, I keep getting those problems.

Now, if I try linking ACML through cmake, I get another, even more interesting set of problems.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libacml_mp.so, needed by /usr/lib64/libarmadillo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libgfortran.so.3, needed by /opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_internal_unpack@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_transfer_integer_write@GFORTRAN_1.4'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_concat_string@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_stop_string@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_transfer_character_write@GFORTRAN_1.4'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_st_write_done@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_st_read@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_string_index@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_transfer_integer@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_compare_string@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_transfer_real_write@GFORTRAN_1.4'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_internal_pack@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_pow_i4_i4@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_st_read_done@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib/libacml.so: undefined reference to '_gfortran_st_write@GFORTRAN_1.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/FirstNNTest.dir/build.make:123: FirstNNTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/FirstNNTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Using the following cmakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(FirstNNTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
find_package(ACML REQUIRED)
include_directories(${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${ACML_INCLUDE_DIRS})



set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Network.cpp Network.h Tools.h)
add_executable(FirstNNTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(FirstNNTest ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES} ${ACML_LIBRARIES})
```

I've spent hours on this issue, and I'm this close to just reinstalling my entire OS.

Comment: According to the error message, the problem is not with your project, but with `acml` and `gfortran` libraries. Do you get these libraries (precise names are in the error log)?

Comment: ACML is installed there, but I can't seem to be able to find gfortran.so in that place, or anywhere else on my system.